# How spring batch internally initializes state when using JpaPagingItemReader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch

I've been trying to get my head around how Spring batch actually initializes the state, I cannot find something fairly obvious.

When a step is configured to have a `JpaPagingItemReader`, I believe the data is read from database as pages. I can see methods like `doRead`, `doReadPage` in the implementation which are inherited/overridden from other base classes. If spring batch only expects an `ItemReader` then I'd have expected it to depend only on `read` method, however the `read` method depends on `results` field in one of the abstract classes which has to be hydrated first. So when does this happen? Is there any magic which when included calls certain methods on this implementation when initializing this class?

Answer (score 3):

The `JpaPagingItemReader` is an [ItemStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html), which means its state is saved in the database and restored on a restart.

Since it extends `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`, the `read.count` is saved at chunk boundaries (using `ItemStream#update`) . On a restart, the read count is read from the database and the current page [is calculated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractPagingItemReader.java#L150-L164) based on the page size.

I hope this clarifies how things work internally.